# how to add float value from properties file in ant

Tags: ant

`enter code here`I want to increment my version from property file in ant build.xml
I am using below code.
It is able to increment the version but at the same time it is rounding it eg. 4.1.0 is becoming 5. my property file:

buildversion=4.1.0

my code:

```
  <target name="info">
  <echo>Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant!</echo>
  <propertyfile file="build.properties">

  <entry key="buildversion" type="int" operation="+" value="1"/>
  </propertyfile>
  </target>

  </project>
```

I read about propertyfile and it support only int,date and string. 
How I am able to do it?

Comment: Use separate `int` fields for `major`.`minor`.`build`-`release`, and concatenate them together to a `string` value...

Comment: Hi thanks for help. Can you please show me example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added fields for `major`.`minor`.`release`-`build` and `timestamp`:

```
<target name="info">
  <echo>Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant!</echo>

  <!-- Declare, set and increment the values -->
  <propertyfile file="build.properties">
    <entry key="buildmajor" type="int" default="0"/>
    <entry key="buildminor" type="int" default="0"/>
    <entry key="buildrelease" type="int" default="0"/>
    <entry key="buildbuild" type="int" default="0" operation="+" value="1"/>
    <!-- ISO timestamp -->
    <entry key="buildtime" type="date" value="now" pattern="yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"/>
  </propertyfile>

  <!-- Re-read values -->
  <property file="build.properties"/>

  <!-- Set calculated value based on re-read values -->
  <propertyfile file="build.properties">
    <entry key="buildversion"
           value="${buildmajor}.${buildminor}.${buildrelease}-${buildbuild}"/>
  </propertyfile>
</target>
```

### Edited the above snippet to re-read changed values before calculating version string.

Also added some comments...